# Python removing duplicates in list and 1==1.0 True

Tags: python, set, duplicates

I need to remove duplicates values in a list, but with `set()` or `for ... if not in...` loop I only get partially correct decisions.
For example for `['asd', 'dsa', 1, '1', 1.0]`

I get:

```
['asd', 'dsa', 1, '1']
```

but the required result is:

```
['asd', 'dsa', 1, '1', 1.0]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not really a duplicate of the previous question, which was specifically about sets, whereas here the OP wants to make the list unique (for a particular definition of unique) without apparent constraints on the implementation. Also note that the answer to the previous question doesn't help the OP at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
In [3]: [value for _, value in frozenset((type(x), x) for x in l)]
Out[3]: [1.0, '1', 1, 'dsa', 'asd']
```

We create a (temporary) [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of tuples containing both element and its type - to keep elements that are equal (such as *1*, *1.0* and *True*) but have different types. Then we iterate over it, unpack tuples and retrieve elements (`value`).

Sure, we could as well use ordinary `set`, which is mutable, but we don't need mutability because our set is temporary.

Note that this won't necessarily preserve the original order.

---

If you need the original order preserved, use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which is a hash map (just like regular [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict)) and therefore works similarly to `frozenset`/`set`

```
In [16]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [17]: [value for _, value in OrderedDict.fromkeys((type(x), x) for x in l)]
Out[17]: ['asd', 'dsa', 1, '1', 1.0]
```

Comment: It's not so much that `hash((int, 1)) != hash((float, 1.0))` but that `(int, 1) != (float, 1.0)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good case for the [decorate-sort-undecorate pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), with the sort part modified to just create a set:

```
dest = [el for el, ignore
        in set((x, type(x))
               for x in src)]
```

The decoration step adds element type to the set, so that e.g. 1 and 1.0 compare different. The final list is then obtained by undecorating the set, i.e. removing the no longer needed type objects.